# Is computational linguistics a good field to go into?

Tags: computational-linguistics

My #1 passion in life is linguistics, and I’ve been obsessed with it for as long as I can remember, but a lot of the basic linguistics jobs such as translators and the such make low wages per year. I want a high paying job that has to do with my linguistics skill, so naturally, seeing as programming seems to be the way to go, computational linguistics seemed like a good idea. However, browsing through Quora answers, it seems that the field is bleak and unpromising. I am not sure how credible Quora is, but it doesn’t seem UNcredible either.

If I get a job in just programming without language, I know I’ll be miserable, even if I make a lot of money. Is computational linguistics a good path to follow? If it is, how would I go about learning it? Is there another job that doesn’t involve CS at all that involves linguistics, that pays well? (50k-100k a year, or more). What needs need to be filled by advanced linguistic knowledge in our world today?

I would really appreciate this because I know I want to do something with linguistics, but I want to be able to make decent money as well. Currently I am working on a language course/program based on years and years of research, including stuff like understanding syllables instead of words, comprehensible input, learning whole phrases as opposed to individual words, viscerally learning words based on motivations, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because building a professional career, not about the Linguistics itself

Comment: I'm voting to close because it's very obviously opinion based and it was always going to be closed. I've also given it an upvote, though. Good luck...

Comment: While, as the other commentators wrote, this question is too opinion-based for a question on the main site, you could try your luck in the informal [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1336/lgwstks) once you've reached 20 reputation.

Comment: https://www.indeed.com/salaries/Computational-Linguist-Salaries

Answer (score 3):

Linguists tend to be most interested in figuring out why language works the way it does. You seem to be more interested in how language works, which is closer to applied linguistics than to linguistics proper.

I don't know of a good way to make top dollar as a linguist, alas.